# S3 Invalid Resource in bucket policy

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to make my entire S3 bucket public, but when I try to add the policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1454540872039",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1454540868094",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sneakysnap/*",
      "Principal": {
      "AWS": [
         "985506495298"
    ]
  }
  }
  ]
}
```

It tells me that my "Resource is invalid", but that is definitely the right `arn` and that is definitely the right bucket name. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't appear to definitely be the right bucket name.  `<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>sneakysnap</BucketName>`

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, my bucket is called "sneakysnap" @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: It can't be, unless S3 is having some kind of a propagation issue. See `http://sneakysnap.s3.amazonaws.com` for confirmation. You might try creating a (-nother) bucket of that name... which should be impossible and will fail if that's already yours... and succeed if not.  I suspect a strange character in there somewhere.  Names are case sensitive.

Comment: I believe you, but I even copy and pasted the becket name @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a leading / before the name of your bucket? Regardless the S3 service keeps returning the bucket doesn't exist.    <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>sneakysnap</BucketName>

Answer (score 92):

I had this "problem" when I was trying to set a policy on the wrong bucket. That is, my arn in the policy was reading `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-A/*` but I was attempting to set it on `my-bucket-B`

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. Make sure that S3 bucket policies only name the bucket that you're applying them against.

Comment: We need a facepalm button together with the upvoting. Thanks!

Comment: Amazon should make it so that you can use a keyword when adding a policy to a resource that refers to itself, something like: arn:aws:s3:::${aws:self}

Comment: Was about to break everything around me now, thanks mate

Answer (score 8):

I had solved the problem by this

> arn:aws:s3:::**your-bucket-name-here**/*

'

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem!

I was using wrong bucket name so I correct it.
It worked for me!
**Best of Luck !**

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. I was not using the correct resource name.
I did change the resource name to exactly the bucket for which I was creating the `bucket policy` e.g

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abc/*"
```

to

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abc12/*"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a policy for an access point it appears that aws will only accept the following format:
i) account id and region must be specified; and
ii) the literal string object must be included (object is not my bucket name)

arn:aws:s3:region:accountid:accesspoint/myaccesspointname/object/*

I found this answer here -> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=315596

Comment: I also found it was necessary to add `.../object/...` to the resource ARN for the `s3:GetObject` action (but not for the "s3:ListBucket" action). Oh, AWS people, where is this documented?! (As of Aug. 2022, the link to "forums.aws.amazon.com" no longer works.)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and the following could fix your error. I hope this helps anyone facing the same. You need to specify the account ID that corresponds to the region for your load balancer and bucket.

```
  "Principal": {
  "AWS": [
     "*********"
```

Please refer to this & update accordingly. This would solve this issue.
See also the Bucket Permissions section of [Access Logs for Your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-logging-bucket-permissions).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error as well. The following change fixed it... No idea why.

This bucket threw the error: *bleeblahblo-stuff*

This worked: *bleeblahblostuff*

Maybe it was the dash.... Maybe the bucket length... Or maybe a combination of the two?? Both buckets had the same settings. Hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the missing region in the arn for govcloud - so the resource had to be

"arn:aws-us-gov:s3:::grcsimpletest"

rather than

"arn:aws:s3:::grcsimpletest"

Strangely the policy that failed was from an AWS doc....  That said, it kind of clicked when I edited the policy in the S3 console and it showed the bucket arm on the edit screen.

Comment: Thank you! One small correction: the `aws`/`aws-us-gov` is the partition, not the region.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when I created my S3 bucket, by default the following were true:

**Manage public access control lists (ACLs)**

```
Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects (Recommended)
True

Remove public access granted through public ACLs (Recommended)
True
```

**Manage public bucket policies**

```
Block new public bucket policies (Recommended)
True

Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies (Recommended)
True
```

I had to set these all to false in order for me to change my bucket policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying the AWS startup workshop, try to close the website-bucket-policy.json file, an re-open it. It works for me, and I guess the update of the json file is not saved automatically unless you close it.

Answer (score 0):

See if the bucket name you are specifying in Resource exists or not. The above answer from Vitaly solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

the problem I realized I had was that my bucket had a ".com" extension which needs to be included in your arn

Answer (score 0):

To add to [iamsohel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004793/10907864). I had this same issue when trying to set an S3 policy for enabling Elastic load balancer access logs using **Terraform**.

**Here's the policy I was trying to set**:

[Access logs for your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::elb-account-id:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix/AWSLogs/your-aws-account-id/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix/AWSLogs/your-aws-account-id/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I wanted to add some variables to the policy. My initial policy looked like this:

```
bucket_policy = <<EOF
                {
                  "Version": "2012-10-17",
                  "Statement": [
                    {
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "*"
                      },
                      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name.2}"
                    },
                    {
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": {
                        "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
                      },
                      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name.2}",
                      "Condition": {
                        "StringEquals": {
                          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": {
                        "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
                      },
                      "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name.2}"
                    }
                  ]
                }
                EOF
```

But this was throwing an error:

> Error: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource
> │       status code: 400, request id: 3HHH9QK9SKB1V9Z0, host id: 8mOrnGi/nsHIcz59kryeriVExU7v+XgGpTw64GHfhjgkwhA3WKSfG7eNbgkMgBMA8qYlyUTLYP8=
> │
> │   with module.s3_bucket_policy_1.aws_s3_bucket_policy.main,
> │   on ../../../../modules/aws/s3-bucket-policy/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "main":
> │    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "main" {

All I had to do was to add `/*` to the end of the arn for the bucket resource:

```
bucket_policy = <<EOF
                {
                  "Version": "2012-10-17",
                  "Statement": [
                    {
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "*"
                      },
                      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name.2}/*"
                    },
                    {
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": {
                        "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
                      },
                      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name.2}/*",
                      "Condition": {
                        "StringEquals": {
                          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": {
                        "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
                      },
                      "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name.2}"
                    }
                  ]
                }
                EOF
```